# Not having all elements touching the sides of the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, border

In my program I have my elements organized to be stacked on top of each other, the only problem here is that they stretch horizontally to touch all edges of the `JFrame`, and I do not want this and cannot for the life of me figure out how to stop this from happening.

Below is my code, much thanks.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


@SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "unused" })
public class MedGUITest extends JFrame {

        private JLabel medName;
        private JLabel medTime;
        private JLabel medDose;
        private JLabel finished;

        private JTextField textFieldMed;
        private JTextField textFieldTime;
        private JTextField textFieldDose;

        private JButton submitButton;
        private JButton meds;
        static int winWidth = 300;
        static int winLength = 300;

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(winWidth,winLength);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        public MedGUITest() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
            panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            add(panel);

                setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                medName = new JLabel("Type Medication Here:");
                panel.add(medName);

                textFieldMed = new JTextField("",15);
                panel.add(textFieldMed);

                medDose = new JLabel("Type Medication Dose:");
                panel.add(medDose);

                textFieldDose = new JTextField("",15);
                panel.add(textFieldDose);

                medTime = new JLabel("Type Medication Time:");
                panel.add(medTime);

                textFieldTime = new JTextField("",15);
                panel.add(textFieldTime);

                submitButton = new JButton("Click Here to Add");
                submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                String medName = textFieldMed.getText();
                                String medDose = textFieldDose.getText();
                                String medTime = textFieldTime.getText();
                                File med = new File("med.txt");

                                try(PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(med,true))) {
                                        out.println("Medication: " + medName + " " +"Dosage: "+ medDose + " Mg"+ " " +"Time of day: "+ medTime);
                                        String lastMed = ("Medication: " + medName + " " +"Dosage: "+ medDose + " Mg"+ " " +"Time of day: "+ medTime+ "\n");
                                        finished.setText("Your Med has been added");
                                        Timer t = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                                finished.setText(null);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        t.setRepeats(false);
                                        t.start();
                                        ta.append(lastMed);
                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                        e1.printStackTrace();
                                }

                        }

                });
                panel.add(submitButton);

                final File med = new File("med.txt");

                if(med.exists()){

                }else{
                meds = new JButton("Click Here to see meds");
                meds.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                if(med.exists()){
                                try {
                                        ta.read(new FileReader("med.txt"),null);

                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                        e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                panel.add(ta);}

                        }
                }); 
                panel.add(meds);
                }


                finished = new JLabel("");
                panel.add(finished);


                if(med.exists()){
                ta.read(new FileReader("med.txt"),null);
                panel.add(ta);}
        }



        public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{



        MedGUITest gui = new MedGUITest();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("Standard GUI");

        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an `EmptyBorder` to the content pane...

```
getContentPane().setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

You could also consider using a layout manager which provides "padding", personally, I'd prefer `GridBagLayout`, but you could also look at [`FlowLayout(int align, int hgap, int vgap)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#FlowLayout(int,%20int,%20int)), but this will effect the spacing between ALL components, not just with the frame

Have a look at [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for some more ideas